# WhatCount field on Task object?

Tags: api

So on this Salesforce [reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_task.htm) there is a `WhatCount` field with a description:

> Available to organizations that have Shared Activities enabled. Count of related TaskRelations pertaining to WhatId. Count of the WhatId must be 1 or less.

So Shared Activities are used for relating multiple Contacts to tasks. What is the use of `WhatCount` if it has this restriction and we can't relate tasks to multiple 'What' objects?

Comment: Looks like I misread the docs. I'm not entirely sure what the point of having a counter is if it can only go to one.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that it doesn't have much use to end-users *as it currently stands* and is *most likely* used internally

We *know* the following:

- `WhatCount` (along with `WhoCount`) is exposed when `Shared Activities` is enabled
- [TaskRelation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_taskrelation.htm) is exposed when `Shared Activities` is enabled
- You can programmatically insert/delete `TaskRelation` records.
- An error is thrown if you attempt to related multiple `whatId` records to a single task through `TaskRelation`

It seems to me `WhatCount` is just a rollup field just as `WhoCount` is. The only reason `WhoCount` has value is because Contacts are opened up to be related to multiple times to a single Task. The fact that there's a restriction for the `WhatId` is what makes it, currently, useless. However, that also means you know they have to rollup that number, anyway, to enforce that restriction.

You'll get the following error trying to insert a TaskRelation records to another `WhatId`

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
> error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, You can only add up to one what
> relation.: [TaskId]

If that restriction were ever to be removed - it would then have equal value as `WhoCount` does. Until that, if ever, happens - there's probably no real value for it. Considering, for any query it'd be more performative with the lookup indexed to just do `WhatId != null` vs. `WhatCount = 1`.

---

Interestingly, there's *some* semblance of multiple whatId relations if you've enabled [Roll Up of Activities to a Contact’s Primary Account](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customizeactivities_activities_account_rollup.htm&type=5). That, along with `Shared Activities`, means that technically you'd see a single task on multiple Account's histories. TaskRelation has an `AccountId` field separate from the `RelationId` that is used in this case. This means you could relate a single Task to a Case and it'd also be displayed on all the primary accounts of the multiple contacts on the Task. However, the `WhatCount` will be `1` as that's summarized by the `RelationId` field.

Comment: Perhaps they are working on multiple WhatId functionality so they added this field in advance?